# How to configure express.js's `app.use(express.static(...)`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using express.js's `app.use(express.static(...))` to serve my files. I'd like to configure some restricted files and make routings (such as redirecting requests ending in `.png` to a specific folder). Is this possible?

Comment: You can maybe configure multiple `static()`s for different [URL paths/prefixes](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use). But, a single instance isn't capable of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get what you need from the express.static middleware, however most of these are easy to implement.
To setup restricted files, simply put a middleware above your express.static middleware in the gist of:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  if (req.url == "/path/to/bad/file") res.send(403)
  else next();
})
```

to setup redirection (using the same type of middleware), you have two options either perform res.redirect("real path") or send the file yourself using res.sendFile("path"), which is more or less what express.static does.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you very much! If you could just expand a little bit your snippet for completion it would be perfect. For example, it's not clear how to integrate app.use(yourfunction) with app.use(express.static(...)). Just place them one before other or what? And to redirect, just call res.redirect("real path") and then next() on the function defined before app.use(express.static(...))?

Comment: yes, just put app.use(your funciton) before app.use(express.static), app.use is basically a stack, if you call next() it moves to the next in the stack, you'll need to have your middleware before express.static.

to redirect you just do res.redirect(url), no need to do next() since once you send a result, you are done.
note that res.redirect will redirect the browser (so that in effect, you'll then get another call to the actual static url)

Comment: Remember you can put `app.use(app.router)` either above or below your `express.static`, depending on whether you want requests to hit your routes first, or static files first. Also remember, once a function sends an HTTP response, Express won't invoke the middleware chain further.